# Matlab file concatenation

Tags: matlab, file, concatenation

I have data files that look like this

```
2 FP1 0 9.064
2 FP1 1 6.622
2 FP1 2 4.669
2 FP1 3 3.693
2 FP1 4 3.693
2 FP1 5 3.693
2 FP1 6 4.181
2 FP1 7 4.181
2 FP1 8 5.157
2 FP1 9 6.134
2 FP1 10 7.111
2 FP1 11 7.111
2 FP1 12 5.646
2 FP1 13 4.669
2 FP1 14 3.693
2 FP1 15 4.181
```

there are several of these files and I want to concatenate all the files with such data; I used the following :

```
d=dir('*.m');  % get the list of files
x=[];            % start w/ an empty array
for i=1:length(d)
x=[x; load(d(i).name)];   % read/concatenate into x
end
save('newfile.m',x)
```

However, I get the following error,

```
 Error using load
  Unknown text on line number 1 of ASCII file co2a0000364.rd.002.m
 "FP1".
```

How can I concatenate all of the data from all of the files and include the characters FP1 etc?

Comment: The data is in .m files???

Answer (score 0):

Using load() to read data from a textfile is wrong. With load() one loads saved Matlab variables. Use importdata()

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html

Or check out the following options

https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/ways-to-import-text-files.html